# ItemsControl Grid.Row Grid.Column Binding in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, binding, grid, itemscontrol

I'm trying to fill a Grid using different X and Y values for Grid.Row and Grid.Column using an ItemsControl, I copied it from a WPF project of mine and can't get it to work in Silverlight (Windows Phone).

Here is a simplified version of it:

ViewModel which the DataContext is set to:

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<GridItem> Data { get; set; }

    public ViewModel()
    {
        Data = new ObservableCollection<GridItem>();
        FillData();
    }

    // fill Data property with some random color GridItems
    private void FillData()
    {
        string[] colors = { "Red", "Green", "Yellow", "Blue" };
        Random r = new Random();

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            Data.Add(new GridItem(i, i, colors[r.Next(colors.Length)]));
        }
    }
}

public class GridItem
{
    public int X { get; set; }
    public int Y { get; set; }
    public string Color { get; set; }

    public GridItem(int x, int y, string color)
    {
        X = x;
        Y = y;
        Color = color;
    }
}
```

The XAML:

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">

    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Data}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>                    
            <Grid Background="Orange">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition />
                    <ColumnDefinition />
                    <ColumnDefinition />
                    <ColumnDefinition />
                    <ColumnDefinition />
                    <ColumnDefinition />
                    <ColumnDefinition />
                    <ColumnDefinition />
                    <ColumnDefinition />
                    <ColumnDefinition />
                    <ColumnDefinition />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition />
                    <RowDefinition />
                    <RowDefinition />
                    <RowDefinition />
                    <RowDefinition />
                    <RowDefinition />
                    <RowDefinition />
                    <RowDefinition />
                    <RowDefinition />
                    <RowDefinition />
                    <RowDefinition />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            </Grid>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Ellipse 
                    Grid.Row="{Binding Y}" 
                    Grid.Column="{Binding X}"
                    Fill="{Binding Color}"
                    Stroke="White" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
</Grid>
```

This is the result (it placed all ellipses on top of eachother):

[image: Result]

While it should have done this:

[image: intention]

Does anyone know why this doesn't work?

Comment: When does your viewmodel get set? Is it before or after InitializeComponent?

Comment: The ViewModel (DataContext) needs to be set **before** InitializeComponent. The values for X and Y need to be set for binding

Comment: @ShawnKendrot I've never seen that before, but I tried anyway and it makes no difference.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the binding for the Grid.Row and Grid.Column within the ContentPresenter rather than as part of the DataTemplate that defines the Ellipse:

```
    <ItemsControl.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="ContentPresenter">
            <Setter Property="Grid.Row" Value="{Binding Y}"/>
            <Setter Property="Grid.Column" Value="{Binding X}"/>
        </Style>
    </ItemsControl.Resources>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate> 
        <DataTemplate> 
            <Ellipse  
                Fill="{Binding Color}" 
                Stroke="White" /> 
        </DataTemplate> 
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: When I do that it throws a XamlParseException: "Cannot set read-only property"

Answer (score 0):

It's because the `DataTemplate` wraps its content in a `ContentPresenter`.  The `Grid.Row` and `Grid.Column` properties only apply to direct descendants so in this case they are not relevant because they are two levels deep in the control hierarchy.

The `ContentPresenter` is added dynamically at run time when the `DataTemplate` renders.  To make this work you'd need to hook into the dynamic generation of the items and set the `Row` and `Column` attached properties on the containing item.

There is a blog post showing one way of getting this working at: http://www.scottlogic.co.uk/blog/colin/2010/11/using-a-grid-as-the-panel-for-an-itemscontrol/